# checkbox in table in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to have a table that contains words and their meaning from database, in another column i want to have checkbox for each row, that user will check them and show what words he/she know.
i have two question in this case:
1- how can i hide the meaning in the first and after clicking in show meaning visible them?
2- how can i set checkboxes?
i have this code until now but it doesn't work
please help me if you can

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMeanings(){
        document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').item(0).style.visiblility = 'visible';
        }
</script>
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
  or die(mysql_error());   
  if (!$con) { 
                                        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
                                    } 
                                    mysql_select_db("project", $con)
                                    or die(mysql_error());
                                    $result = mysql_query("select * from words");
                                    echo "<table border='1'>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>word</th>
                                        <th>meaning</th>
                                        <th>check</th>
                                        </tr>";
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                      {
                                      echo "<tr>";
                                      echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
                                      echo "<td>";
                                      echo "<div";
                                      echo "class='hiding' style='visibility:hidden'>" . $row['meaninig'];
                                      echo "</div>";
                                      echo "</td>";
                                      echo "<td>";
                                      echo "<input";
                                      echo "type= 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox' id = 'checkbox' value = '' />";
                                      echo "</td>";
                                      echo "</tr>";
                                      }
                                      echo "</table>";
                                      mysql_close($con);                                                                                   
                                ?>

                                </div>
                                <button onclick="ShowMeanings()">showmeaning</button>
```

Comment: do you by any change know jquery?

Comment: could you show any errors or debug code. Also $row['meaninig'] is misspelled... not sure if that is by design? :)

Comment: i know that is missplelled, but i didnt change the column of my table in database
i hava an erro that is here:
document.getElementsByClassName(...).item(...) is null document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').item(0).style.visiblility = 'visible'

Answer (score 0):

For hide a suggestion:

```
 echo "class='hiding' style='display:none'>" . $row['meaninig'];
```

To show the meaning:

```
//for Jquery

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMeanings(){
           $('.hiding').shoW();
        }
</script>
```

Or

```
 //for plain old javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function ShowMeanings(){
                  document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').style.visibility = 'visible';
                }
        </script>
```

Your code Edited:

```
<html><head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMeanings(){
           $('.hiding').shoW();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
  or die(mysql_error());   
  if (!$con) { 
                                        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
                                    } 
                                    mysql_select_db("project", $con)
                                    or die(mysql_error());
                                    $result = mysql_query("select * from words");
                                    echo "<table border='1'>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>word</th>
                                        <th>meaning</th>
                                        <th>check</th>
                                        </tr>";
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                      {
                                      echo "<tr>";
                                      echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
                                      echo "<td>";
                                      echo "<div";
                                      echo "class='hiding' style='display:none'>" . $row['meaninig'];
                                      echo "</div>";
                                      echo "</td>";
                                      echo "<td>";
                                      echo "<input";
                                      echo "type= 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox' id = 'checkbox' value = '' />";
                                      echo "</td>";
                                      echo "</tr>";
                                      }
                                      echo "</table>";
                                      mysql_close($con);                                                                                   
                                ?>

                                </div>
                                <button onclick="ShowMeanings()">showmeaning</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: i have this line in my code:
echo "class='hiding' style='visibility:hidden'>" . $row['meaninig'];
but the function showmeaning doesn't work
i want to have third column that contains checkbox that user can check it (check that he/she knows the meaning or not)

Comment: that is a suggestion, also what do you mean in your number 2

Comment: @fahimeh so what you want is to show the meaning for all hidden meanings for all checkboxes? updated my code to show all meanings when button is click, if you want it to view only specific meanings for each checkboxes i would suggest you change your code

Comment: i want after user click on button show meaning of all the words and then he/she check what words he/she knows

Comment: @fahimeh then thats the code for you give it a try. updated it for you

Comment: @fahimeh updated the javascript code again since you were using visibility

Comment: i tried what you said but i have an error:
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).style is undefined
 

    document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').style.visibility = 'visible';

Comment: @fahimeh I would suggest changing your visbility to the one i suggested above as it will be much much more easier for you. here is a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/tG8Lx/2/, this is using above example and with jquery

Comment: in this way i have no error but the show meaning function does't work again

Comment: @fahimeh did you follow this echo "class='hiding' style='display:none'>"

Comment: yes
here is my code:
echo "class='hiding' style='display:none'>" . $row['meaninig'];

Comment: @fahimeh try copy and pasting your updated code on my answer, it should work, check console for any error

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it does't work for my project
maybe the problem is somewhere else
i dont want to disturb you
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClassName` is an inexistant function. You mean `getElementsByClassName`, which will however return a list of the elements, so you need to select one.

`document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').item(0).style.visibility = 'visible';`

Comment: @fahimeh Will you try this

Comment: Are you sure? I even tested it and works fine. Your implementation must be wrong. Try to use an `alert`  or similar on your `ShowMeanings` function to see if the `onclick` event is really ran.

Comment: yes
i have an error:
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).item(...) is null
 

document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').item(0).style.visiblility = 'visible'